# Sorting array with compactMap by date Swift 5

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, realm

I am trying to return a transaction array sorted by the date. How can I accomplish this in the swift 5 programming language?

Date:

> 2021-03-19 23:30:30 +0000

**I have a transaction object like so:**

```
import RealmSwift

class Transaction: Object {

    @objc dynamic var identifier: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var currency: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var date: Date = Date()
    @objc dynamic var amount: Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var transactionDescription: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var transactionState: String = "SUCCESS"
 
}
```

**Function returning the the array:**

```
 public func getAllTransactions() -> [Transaction] {
        return realm.objects(Transaction.self).compactMap({ $0 })
    }
```

**PSUEDO example:**

```
return realm.objects(Transaction.self).sorted(byKeyPath "date")
```

Comment: Your "pseudo example" seems to be correct. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Cannot convert return expression of type 'Results<Transaction>' to return type '[Transaction]'

Comment: Oh you need an array. Well, you can just do `Array(realm.objects(Transaction.self).sorted(byKeyPath "date"))` instead. But consider this, are you sure you don't want to return a `Results<Transaction>` instead? Converting it to an array would mean loading all the transactions into memory.

Comment: Now I understand what I was doing wrong. You are correct.

Comment: @Sweeper is 100% on point. You should carefully consider the size of your dataset when casting Realm Results objects to an array. Not only does it cause it to load *all* objects into memory, they also 'disconnect' from Realm and are no longer live updating objects.